# Multiple inheritance and MRO (method order resolution) and variable __init__ arguments of parent classes?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to design class `NamedAndOrdered` from `Named` and `Ordered` and found that is not easy because both parent class has different `__init__()` arguments list see example it tell more than this description. I have long experience in Python but still not know how to solve this case - can you share some experience.

```
class Named(object):
  def __init__(self, name):
    super(Named, self).__init__()
    self.name = name
    print type(Named), self.name

    class Ordered(object):
      def __init__(self, order):
        super(Ordered, self).__init__()
        self.order = order
        print type(Ordered), self.order

    class NameAndOrdered(Named, Ordered):
      def __init__(self):
        super(NameAndOrdered, self).__init__(1)
        print 'name', self.name
        print 'order', self.order

    nameAndOrdered = NameAndOrdered()
```

This code not works gives `TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)` because `Named` try to call `Ordered` whatever `Named` should not know `Ordered` sice can defined somewhere else.

How can I solve problem with initialization if `Named` need some different arguments than `Orderd`?

This example is abstract it is simplifiedas much as possible to show problem to solve.

Comment: Worth a read: [Python's Super is nifty, but you can't use it](https://fuhm.net/super-harmful/).

Comment: First of all, your `NamedAndOrdered.__init__()` needs to take *both* `named` and `order` arguments - how else could you pass those to the respective superclasses' `__init__()` methods. Then I would suggest not to use `super`, but call the superclasses explicitely, and in the order you want/need them to: `Named.__init__(self, name); Ordered.__init__(self, order)`

Comment: It looks it is better not create multiple inheritance with variable __init__ constructors or try to use dynamic keywords and split for partial initialization.

Comment: Yes, keyword arguments are another solution. Or explicitely calling your superclasses' intializers like I described.

Comment: @LukasGraf It will not work `Named.__init__(self, name)` will call `super(Name, self).__init__()` what mean in this MRO `Ordered.__init__()` what is wrong - it will give `TypeError`.

Comment: @LukasGraf Keywords can be also solution I will try keywords since better works with `super()` - it will allow code faster with some small risk.

Comment: Yes, for that to work you would have to avoid the use of `super` in `Named` and `Ordered`  as well as described in the article.

Comment: Both methods is good `super()` and bound calls.